# Install 32 bit files and 64 bit registry settings in WiX installer

Tags: windows, dll, wix, windows-installer

Can I set up a 64-bit registry key to refer to a 32-bit program files path using WiX?

I'm writing a plugin for another piece of software. I want my plugin dll to go in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.dll` *not* in `C:\Program Files\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.dll` because the dll is 32-bit, not 64-bit.

*However*, I need the registry key to go in `HKLM/Software/Company/Product/Etc....` *not* in `HKLM/Wow6432Node/Software/Company/Product/Etc....` because the process that actually reads the registry key is 64-bit. That 64-bit process reads the registry and launches a 32-bit process to sandbox the dll.

Is there any way to do this? I've tried using different components with different `Win64` attribute values, and even putting them in separate component groups. However, I keep getting these build errors (not warnings):

```
ICE80: This 64BitComponent RegistryComponent uses 32BitDirectory INSTALLFOLDER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you support 32-bit and 64-bit machines you need two separate MSI setups:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

So your 32-bit install creates any COM entries for any 32-bit Clients and the 64-bit setup has 32-bit and 64-bit components that write to the registry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This seems like the correct answer to me. I think they can be combined using Burn: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat poor solution, but you could just a custom action to add registry entries, if you don't mind them sticking around after an uninstall.

If you write a custom action in C# you can just do something like this:

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
    // do it
}
```

Comment: I will admit that I occasionally do this.  Sometimes I have an install that's 99% x86 and 1% x64 and I'll go against my normal believes and do a little out of the box magic to hit a single registry entry or something.  The alternative is a full on 32bit and 64bit msi with a bootstrapper / chainer to encapsulate it all.   Windows Installer's 1 platform per .MSI is quite lame in my opinion.

Comment: It's kind of gross to leave registry entries there after install

Comment: @Hans Agreed. If I'm not mistaken you could also write a custom action that will delete those same registry entries, and make it run when uninstalling.

Answer (score 2):

A rather easy solution to only have one installer version for 32 and 64 bit is to export a .reg file with the keys you want to add (from regedit) and then run a custom action during install, ie:

`<CustomAction Id='Add_Registry_Keys' Execute='deferred' Directory='DriverDir' Impersonate='no' ExeCommand='regedit.exe /s &quot;[DriverDir]default.reg' Return='ignore' />`

Comment: Again, it's kind of gross to leave registry entries there after install

Comment: I agree! With the command line tool "reg" one could delete the registry keys again on uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress ICE errors also, not just warnings. This means you **can** use Win64 attributes in your x86 msi.
The setting to ignore ICE validations is found in the Project Properties under the Tool Settings tab.

It might not be recommended, but if it works its still better than the alternative of a custom action.

Comment: I saw mixed results with this solution. It worked fine on Per-Machine install context but only installed the 64bit registry value when using Per-User context. Both components were nearly identical with only Win64 and Guid attributes differing, with only a RegistryKey and RegistryValue component inside.